# How to fetch wordpress posts through query() and output them in json?

Tags: php, android, arrays, wordpress, jsonp

This code is working fine and pulling the blog posts but the only problem is that i want the data to be in a json array so that i can create an api with that and show posts outside...

```
<?php
require('/home/dealicopter/public_html/wp-load.php');
function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat' => 7,
);
query_posts($args); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php 
    $permalink = the_permalink();
    $title = the_title();
    $age = array("id"=>$permalink, "title"=>$title); 
    ?>
    <?php echo json_encode($age); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: echo "[]"; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress comes with an build-in API that returns JSON. you can hook in this as follows

`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter%5Bposts_per_page%5D=-1`

[API Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

if you want to make custom code I recommend using `wp_send_json()` create a new template file in you theme / child theme with the following code then create a new page and select the tempalte file in the page attribute

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Template Name
*/

add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat' => 7,
);

$output = array();
query_posts($args);

if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $permalink = get_the_permalink();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $output[] = array("id"=>$permalink, "title"=>$title); 
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_send_json($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the function.php theme file

```
<?php
function get_post()
{
    $args_query = array(
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'nopaging' => true,
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args_query);
    $data = null;
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $data[] = array('title' => get_the_title(), 'content' => get_the_content(), 'link' => get_the_permalink());
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    if ($data != null) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'data' => $data));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'msg' => 'post not found'));
    }


    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_post', 'get_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post', 'get_post');
?>
```

Javascript file code:

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $('button').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "https://********.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: {
                    'action': 'get_post'
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```